# Drag & drop of files from the file system into Flex doesn't work

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop, air

I am trying to implement drag & drop of files from the file system into Flex, but somehow it doesn't work.

To be precise, it refuses to register when the nativeDragEnter event happens, meaning, it doesn't do anything when i drag a file system file into a component. I tried it with mx and spark components, using flex 3.6A and 4.10  but nothing works.

I am working on Windows 8.1.  Could this be the problem?

Below is what i did, did i miss something?

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function hbox1_nativeDragEnterHandler(event:NativeDragEvent):void
        {
            var a:String = "segdfsh";

        }


    ]]>
</mx:Script>


<mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" nativeDragEnter="hbox1_nativeDragEnterHandler(event)">

</mx:HBox>
```

Comment: Works just fine on Windows 7. Have you tried the dragEnter instead of nativeDragEnter ? Add a background color to your HBox to make sure it fills out the whole app

Comment: for some reason it dosnt work when i try to compile and debug it from Flash builder, but when i release the project as a desktop aplication, then it works, so yeah...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question seems to work after all, but for some reason it didn't work if i debug it from Flashbuilder, but when i release my project, then it works like a charm, so yeah, no issue here, i guess.